# generic type is inferred from wrong argument

Tags: typescript

I am using `NoInfer` from [ts-toolbelt](https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/function_noinfer.html).

Unfortunately it doesn't have any effect in the example below.

The generic type is inferred from the `util` function as soon as it is present.

You can see that:

- for `demo1` no function argument is used and the type is: `{ foo: string }`
- for `demo2` a function argument `_` is used and the type is `unknown`

Is there any way to ensure that generic type is only inferred from the return value so `demo2` has the same type as `demo1`?

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];

function factory<T>(generator: (util: (u: NoInfer<T>) => void) => T): T {
    return {} as any;
}

const demo1 = factory(() => {
    return {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
})

const demo2 = factory((_) => {
    return {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
})

// works
demo1.foo = "baz";
// ERROR! demo2 is unknown
demo2.foo = "baz";
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgewJIDsBmUBOAeAKgPhgF4YBtXAXXJigA8QoUATAZxgEMUwYB+GABhgAuGCigA3LBQDcwYGgCuKAMYgAlghQw07VQkxg8+ABQBzRlnYh9I4wvUAbWwpG4AlMULiEaph6KE7q4wAN7AMBEwmFAgCphaIQC+HGycYLKJcsqaLCAwTFAAtggAjMTautYGxsb+hGGRUTFxCeGNkQBEaAgIHSIdAEbsmB1tEZmJblk5eQXFAEzlOnrVxgD6daFjTbHxW+2d3b39QyPbE1PAAPRXMADu+gDWLMBzpQB0R+WD7ABeHbIbjAAKIAJVBAHlQQBCfJFBCLNRsJSPFAIO4oV7w+afHrfIb-aRAA)

Comment: I didn't totally understand the aim but can't you just explicitly declare the type? Such as : const demo2 = factory((_:any|unknown) => {})

Comment: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgewJIDsBmUBOAeAKgPhgF4YBtXAXXJigA8QoUATAZxgEMUwYB+GABhgAuGCigA3LBQDcwYGgCuKAMYgAlghQw07VQkxg8+ABQBzRlnYh9I4wvUAbWwpG4AlMULiEaph6KE7q4wAN7AMBEwmFAgCphaIQC+HGycYLKJcsqaLCAwTFAAtggAjMTautYGxsb+hGGRUTFxCeGNkQBEaAgIHSIdAEbsmB1tEZmJblk5eQXFAEzlOnoG2CGkANZQYCK5mGoophS7IPuHiSbGAPp1oWNNsfF37Z3dvf1DI-cTU8AA9H8YAB3fQbFjAOalAB0b3Kg3YAC8OrIATAAKIAJQxAHkMQBCfJFBCLNRsJQbFAIIEoCFE+YwnpwoZI6RAA)

Comment: It's not being inferred from the wrong argument; it fails to be inferred *at all* due to a limitation of TypeScript. The problem is that `_` is *contextually typed* (you didn't annotate it) and the compiler assumes that the fn return type might depend on the type of `_` (not the case in your toy example but is almost always true for real code), so `T` depends on `_`'s type and vice versa and everything falls apart. See [ms/TS#31892](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31892) for an issue where this is explained. Shall I write up an answer or am I missing something about your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const demo2 = factory<{foo: string}>((_) => { /* ... */ }
```

You'll need to explicitly declare the generic type in the function call.